# Can i do Multiple tasks by the conditional operator?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-operator

Can we write multiple commands like in if statement {between brackets} in conditional operators ?
(For knowledge, not for use)

```
    if (x == 1) {
        printf("Printf");
        scanf("%d", &scanf);
        callFun(calling a function);
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        printf("Printf2");
        scanf("%d", &scanf2);
        callFun2(calling a function);
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: `scanf("%d", &scanf);` can you show me usage case?

Comment: What is it are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _Can i do Multiple tasks ..._ Define tasks, you can compile this lines of code (as shown by @0 in an answer) as long as you can separate them with commas as expressions, but will fail with statements like `(x == 1) ? return 0 : ...` or `(x == 1) ? goto fail : ...`

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me. Please rephrase, or provide a comprehensive example close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo(int x)
{
    int g,h;
    (void)( x == 1 ? ( printf("Hello\n"), scanf("%d", &g), callfunc(g)) : x == 2 ? ( printf("Hello2\n"), scanf("%d", &k), callfunc(h + 5)) : 0);
}
```

Very easy to read as you see. Better use `if`s

Comment: Re "*Very easy to read as you see.*", I think you're being sarcastic, but it could be made to be read.  Most programs look bad when you put them all on one line, whether they use the conditional operator or not.

Comment: Yes - It is easy to see that it is sarcastic. But what is the point? Unreadable code and good look to the person having to debug this in the future

Comment: @ikegami ternary operators are format unfriendly. `if`s are. Ternary operators were not designed to carry compound statements so your comment IMO was not considered too good.

Comment: @0___________, I agree that you can usually get cleaner code by avoid it. But the fault it all yours that it's not readable.

Comment: Is it more important to enable reviewers/maintainers to understand the code

Answer (score 1):

**This looks clean in my opinion**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(){
    puts("working");
}
void func1(){
    puts("working 2");
}

int main(){
    int i = 21;
    i == 2122 ? func() : func1();
    return 0;
}
```

**This also works**

```
int main(){
    int i = 21;
    i == 2122 ? (
            puts("working 1"),
            puts("working 2")
            ) : (
                puts("working 3"),
                puts("working 4"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I finally understand what CLISP means :)

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` is less generic than `if` since it requires operands that are expressions. Furthermore it requires both operands to be of the same type. In some cases when they aren't, C implicitly tries to convert them by applying the implicit "usual arithmetic conversions" on the 2nd and 3rd operands. This can lead to unexpected results. For example this code prints gibberish:

```
printf("%d\n", 1 ? 1 : 1.0);
```

Even though the 3rd operand is never evaluated, the 2nd operands gets implicitly promoted to `double` and printing that with `%d` gives undefined behavior.

To avoid subtle stuff like this, the `?:` should be avoided most of the time. It's main purpose in the C language is actually to enable conditions inside function-like macros that return a value. For example we obviously can't write a macro returning a value like this:

```
#define M(cond) if(cond) { foo(); } else { bar(); }
```

But it could be done like this:

```
#define M(cond) ( (cond) ? foo() : bar() )
```

Similarly, the `,` comma operator's main purpose is also to enable such macros. So yeah, you *could* rewrite the code you've written with the `?:` in combination with the comma operator. But it's a very bad idea since such code turns unreadable. The only place where it *might* be justified is inside a function-like macro:

```
#define M(x) ( x==1 ? (printf("Hello\n"),  scanf("%d", &something), callFun(something))  \
             : x==2 ? (printf("Hello2\n"), scanf("%d", &something), callFun2(something)) \
             : 0 )
```

This macro would return whatever `callFun` and `callFun2` returns, assuming they return compatible types.

And in case it isn't obvious, function-like macros like these are very bad practice and actual functions are always preferred when possible. Writing macros such as this is should be a *last resort*, like for example when maintaining some crappy code base where you can't change certain things.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a weird and thus undesireable thing to do, but it can be done.

The key is to use a comma operator instead of separate statements.

```c
(
   x == 1 ? (
      printf("Printf"),
      scanf("%d", &scanf),
      callFun(calling a function)
   )
   : x == 2 ? (
      printf("Printf2"),
      scanf("%d", &scanf2),
      callFun2(calling a function)
   )
   : (void)0
);
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &scanf)` can you explain?

Comment: @0___________, You're asking the wrong person; that's the OP's code.